# How many such numbers are divisible by 3?

Tags: combinatorics

Numbers less than 4000 are formed from the digits 1, 3, 5, 8 and 9, without repetition. How many of them are divisible by 3?

I got 56, but the answer says 50. Did I count something extra?

1 digit: 3, 9. So **2** total in this case.

2 digits:  $\{1,5\},$ $\{1,8\},$ $\{3, 9\}.$ Each give rise to two numbers being divisible by 3, so **6** total in this case.

3 digits: $\{1,8,9\},$ $\{1,5,9\},$ $\{1,3,5\},$ $\{1,8,3\}.$ Each give rise to six numbers being divisible by 3, so **24** total in this case.

4 digits: $\{1,3,5,9\},$ $\{1,3,8,9\}.$ Each give rise to 12 numbers being divisible by 3, so **24** total in this case.

Comment: How did you count 56? We can't tell your mistake if you don't tell us *your* approach.

Comment: Are four digit numbers that start with 5, 8 or 9 less than 4000?

Comment: They do not, but they were never counted to begin with.

Comment: Just checking! I need to carefully go through now...

Comment: I wrote a small program that finds them all and counts them.  It also gets 56, you can find the source code [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24961067/).  The output of it is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24961074/).

Comment: There doesn't look like anything wrong with your reasoning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  The answer key is wrong or somebody misread a $6$ as a $0$.